# Logging of nested stored procedures in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

How do you individually log the information of nested stored procedures that are executed by the parent stored procedure?

Example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.usp_ParentProcedure
AS
BEGIN
    EXEC dbo.usp_ChildProcedure1
    EXEC dbo.usp_ChildProcedure2
    EXEC dbo.usp_ChildProcedure3
END  
GO
```

Ideally I would like to log the transaction time, I/0, CPU usage of each nested stored procedure individually whilst only amending the parent procedure.

The reason being is because the nested procedures are frequently added and removed from the parent procedure by other users, and we all know getting everyone to follow a creation protocol is seriously hard work.

Aaron Bertrand has shared his solution for logging a single stored procedure here
http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2003/simple-process-to-track-and-log-sql-server-stored-procedure-use/

I would appreciate if anyone can help me expand this to cover my scenario above.

Thanks

Neal

Comment: Why not just have a DDL trigger that prevents the creation or alter of any procedure where the body does *not* contain generic logging handlers? They can't bypass your rules if the system doesn't let them. If that is not an option, you can easily wrap the calls themselves in the parent procedure and capture time (easily) and other resources (perhaps a bit tougher) for each call. But ugh. And you'd still be relying on people to wrap new calls with the logging bit - not much different than expecting them to add logging handlers to the child procedures.

Comment: Wow, what a privilege to get a response from a senior consultant at SQL Sentry. Thank you for taking time to respond to my query. I will run the DDL idea past my superiors, and tell them Aaron Bertrand sent me ;)

Comment: Mr. Bertrand do you mean set up a SQL Server policy that would enforce this? How would you set up a ddl trigger that would examine the proc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending some time having a look around the dm tables, I have found running this query **after** executing the **parent** stored procedure returns some useful information about the child stored procedures.

```
SELECT
    DB_NAME (s.database_id),
    s.[object_id],
    p.name,
    s.sql_handle,
    s.plan_handle,
    s.last_worker_time,
    s.last_elapsed_time,
    s.last_physical_reads,
    s.last_logical_writes,
    s.last_logical_reads,
    p2.name,
    p2.[object_id]
FROM sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats s
INNER JOIN sys.procedures p
ON s.[object_id] = p.[object_id]
LEFT JOIN sys.procedures p2 --join to identify parent procedure from results
ON p2.[object_id] = (
    select top 1 s.[object_id]
    from sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats s
    inner join sys.procedures p
    ON s.[object_id] = p.[object_id]
    order by s.total_worker_time desc
)
WHERE s.[object_id] <> p2.[object_id]
AND s.[object_id] <> @@PROCID
```